# Silverlight ScrollViewer not working when containing multiple usercontrols

Tags: silverlight, xaml

I have a page that has a header area and a content area. The content area contains just one usercontrol.
We have a class structure along the lines of AbstractClassA is the base class of all the classes to be displayed. Abstract classes B & C both inherit from A.
Concrete class B1 and B2 inherit from B and Concrete classes C1 and C2 inherit from C.

This user control then contains a number of controls displaying the information for A, plus two additional controls one each for B & C, made visible only if the class being displayed is of the relevant type.

Those addituional controls then display all the fields relevant to their corresponding abstract class, plus have additional controls relating to the concrete classes, again only displayed when underlying class is of the correct type, which then have the fields relating to the concrete class.

This is all working fine except that some of the classes we're dealing with have so many fields they don't fit on the screen anymore. So, obvious thing to do - wrap the content in a scrollviewer.

Only problem is that this doesn't seem to work.

The visibility of the subsequent controls are bound to a property on the viewmodel (via a bool to visibility converter) that determines what type of class is being dealt with. The fallback value is collapsed so they start invisible. Not sure if the required size is somehow failing to get passed to the scrollviewer when they subsequently? As the scrollbar doesn't appear, despite being set to auto. The xaml below

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
  <!-- Divide the page into a row for the header and 1 further rows which are used to position the content -->
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="{StaticResource HeaderRowHeight}" />
    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    <RowDefinition Height="100" />
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>


  <Grid Grid.Row="0"
        Grid.Column="0"
        Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
    <!-- Page header -->
  </Grid>

  <!-- Main page content follows -->
  <Grid Grid.Row="1"
        Width="auto">
    <ScrollViewer Height="700"
                  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
      <dataEdit:CaseTypeInternalEditControl Height="Auto" />
    </ScrollViewer>
  </Grid>
</Grid>
```

I've also tried putting the scrollviewer within the user control, but to no avail. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

The problem wasn't apparent from the question, I'd have needed to post one of the subsequent child controls, whose visibility was determined thus:

```
        <Canvas Visibility="{Binding Path=CaseIsB, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}, FallbackValue=Collapsed}">
            <dataEditControls:CaseBEditControl DataContext="{Binding CaseBEditViewModel}"  />
        </Canvas >
        <Canvas Visibility="{Binding Path=CaseIsC, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}, FallbackValue=Collapsed}">
            <dataEditControls:CaseCEditControl DataContext="{Binding CaseCEditViewModel}"  />
        </Canvas >
```

The problem being that the Canvas object has a size of zero - so wasn't registering anything to the scrollviewer when visible.
As soon as I switched it out for a Grid, everything worked fine...